# CMake export source files

Tags: cmake

I'm looking for a way to export all source files mentioned by CMake files with the same tree structure to Deploy folder.

As an example, I'm building SDK and want to ship source code only for public build.

Comment: To query the source files of a target you can use the SOURCES target property. Does that help you?

Comment: Not really, I need not only Source files, but CmakeFiles as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [cpack](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPack.html) or you can create your own custom "dist" target with 7z, rar, zip, etc..